# Process list of pairs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to go thorough a list of pairs, [(a, a)], but I can't get to make it work. I tried something like:

```
showList :: [(a, a)] -> IO ()
showList (x, y):[] = putStrLn (x, y)
showList (x, y):xs = do 
    putStrLn (x, y)
    showList xs
```

Any solution to this? I'd like something like what I done there.

Comment: There are about 3 or 4 separate errors in this code. Please post the specific error you're asking about.

Comment: @melpomene  "error: Parse error in pattern: showList" is the only error so far. On the line with: showList (x, y):[] = putStrLn (x, y)

Comment: You will need to add a `Show a =>` constraint to the beginning of the type signature, and you need to switch to `print`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces don't affect operator precedence.

`showList (x, y):[]` parses as `(showList (x, y)) : []`.

Function application has higher precedence than any infix operator, including `:`.

You want

```
showList ((x, y) : []) = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest mistake is that you thought that a Tuple is a String.
Tuple `(x, y)` is not a string. 
The signature of `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` wants a String as it's argument.

You can use `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()` that will print anything that has a Show instance.

As a side note: You could've used `mapM_ print` instead.

Comment: If you want to admonish the OP, do so in a comment to the question. It has no place in an answer.